# how to update particular row in a table by going back to form page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a page called form_data_submit.php in which i am entering data through textfields and storing it in database myform in table formdata. I want to show the database with a edit option that will lead me back to form_data_submit.php where i can update my row and update it in my database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to insert and update in same page.
You can use something like `$_GET['page_type']`=update to do update ie: url.com/?page_type=update
And in your php which handles insertion of data to DB you would check

```
if ($_GET['page_type'] == 'update') {
// Do MySQL update
} else {
// Do MySQL insert
}
```

Go luck

Answer (score 0):

You could add the ID as param if you'd like to update:

`form_data_submit.php?id=123`

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    // UPDATE `mytable` SET ... WHERE id = $_GET['id']
} else {
    // INSERT INTO `mytable` ...
}
```

Notice: you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).